# Most platform version agnostic way to get a particular file path?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) library creates files in

> storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[app_name]/files/Pictures/18-Feb-19/1550503112_in.jpg

What would I use to get access to the picture in this path later? 
I'm trying to avoid using a hard-coded string... I've tried googling it but I'm getting really confused as to how to get this path by using Android predefined values like `android.os.environment.datadirectory` or  `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android groups the filesystem into two different types of storage:

1 `Internal Storage` – this is a portion of the file system that can be accessed only by the application or the operating system.

You can access the internal storage using code like this

`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)`

And the path is like this:

`/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files` or `/data/data/{package name}/files`

2 `External Storage` – this is a partition for the storage of files that is accessible by all apps, the user, and possibly other devices. On some devices, external storage may be removable (such as an SD card).

You can access the external storage using code like this

```
Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures)
```

And the path is like this

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package name}/files
```

So you can see the path Media Plugin has created is the external storage path. You can access it using

`Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures)`